# Why does adb push/pull redirect STDOUT to STDERR?

Tags: android, adb

When using 'adb pull ...' the output is sent to stderr regardless of success. Is there any reason for this? For an example, pulling a file that is there and pulling a file that doesn't exist:

When I run:

```
adb pull /data/data/good_file.txt /tmp`
```

I get the following:

```
stdout:
stderr: 0 KB/s (13 bytes in 0.078s)
```

(i.e. no stdout)

Then when when I run:

```
adb pull /data/data/bad_file.txt /tmp
```

I get the following:

```
stdout:
stderr: remote object '/data/bad_file.txt' does not exist
```

The program below was used to generate the above results:

```
from subprocess import Popen
cmd = "adb pull /data/data/good_file.txt /tmp"
p = Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
print cmd
print "stdout: " + out
print "stderr: " + err
```

Comment: I'm actually seeing that simple things like 'adb' are also printing to STDERR

Comment: In the short term if you want to page the output, for example, you could set up an alias like adp='adb 2>&1' so commands like less will work as expected

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue with: `adb install -r /foo/bar.apk` and sound like `adb` always send his result to stderr, just add `2>&1` at end and it solves the problem.

```
cmd = "adb pull /data/data/good_file.txt /tmp 2>&1"
```

> The 2>&1 just redirects Channel 2 (Standard Error) and Channel 1
>   (Standard Output) to the same place which in this context is Channel 1
>   (Standard Output), and thence your log file.